# Styles overwriting in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

I'm using [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) to achieve Metro UI in my app.

I have a listview and MahApps.Metro is changing style for it. MahApps styles for listview are [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.ListView.xaml).

Loading of styles:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedSingleRowTabControl.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/FineRSS;component/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

I need to keep track of selected listviewitems so I'm using the next approach:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But MahApps.Metro's style is overwritten to ListView's default.

What can I do to keep either styles and IsSelected binding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not positive I follow what you're trying to do, but would it make sense to make your `Style` be `BasedOn` the default one that is loaded?

Something like

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle> 
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}"> 
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/> 
    </Style> 
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: although VS doesn't like the line BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}" it seems to be working. thank you.

Comment: Same question I have. Still getting used in working with XAML.